# Informatica Workflow not able to read the parameter file

Tags: parameters, informatica-powercenter

I've a workflow(wf1) that generates a flat file(p1) which will serve as the parameter file for my next workflow(wf2).

Wf2 has been set up to use P1 as the parameter file. But when i run wf2, in the workflow log, i'm getting the VAR_27016 : Warning! Cannot find section for session [s1] and folder [d1] in parameter file error.

However, when i delete the parameter file P1 and manually create it again and run wf2, it's picking the file.

Why is informatica able to pick up the parameter file if created manually but not able to pick it up if created by another workflow?

Comment: Are the generated files *exactly* the same as the manually created ones? Perhaps put each into a file comparison tool to be 100% certain.

Comment: Yes they are, but i found out the issue. Turns out, in my expression, i'm using CHR(13) which translates to carriage return but forgot to use CHR(10) which is line feed. So when the file got created, it automatically got created as a CR file instead of CRLF file.

Comment: Awesome. Good sleuthing! Perhaps you could answer your own question then in case someone else down the road has a similar problem? stackoverflow actually encourages you to do this https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions.

Comment: Yes, i just posted the answer

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, in my expression, i'm using CHR(13) which translates to carriage return but forgot to use CHR(10) which is line feed. So when the file got created, it automatically got created as a CR file instead of CRLF file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of the parameter file. Informatica generates the file with the user it is assigned. You may be creating the parameter file manually with some other user.

Thank you